# How to simplify "Get mean ages for women of every class"

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have the famous titanic dataset, called fr1.

The class column contains the following: 1, 2, 3
The gender column: male, female

I want to obtain the mean ages for females for each class, I think It should be a simpler way to code the following, imagine for example that there are 20 classes instead of 3:

```
c3 = fr1[fr1["class"] ==3]
c3w = fr1[fr1["gender"] =='female']
print(round(c3w["Age"].mean()))
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a ```'``` at the end of ```female```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the females, then `pandas` `groupby` method and apply aggregation function to each group (=for each class):

```
fr1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "class": ["1", "2", "2"],
    "gender": ["female", "female", "female"],
    "age": [30, 25, 18]
})

fr1[fr1["gender"] == "female"] \
    .groupby("class", as_index=False)["age"] \
    .agg(lambda x: round(np.mean(x)))
```

Output:

```
  class  age
0     1   30
1     2   22
```

It could be even simpler, if you skipped the rounding part.

```
fr1[fr1["gender"] == "female"] \
    .groupby("class", as_index=False)["age"] \
    .mean()
```